# Frequency in dfs_query_then_fetch in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, tf-idf

I am trying to fetch docFrequency across all shards for each response. I tried default search(query_then_fetch ) and dfs_query_then_fetch. Both of them returned different score , but the docFrequency was same for the matched result. So, Is the docFrequency **global** in both the cases or is it from a particular shard only in both cases ? And how can i get the global frequency ?